# Retrieve data from multiple joins using eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm developing a project to track deliveries of goods.
My idea would be that one delivery can go to different places, and all those places are connected by single trips.

Here is my Eloquent schema:

```
class Delivery extends Model
{
    public function places()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Place::CLASS, 'delivery_id');
    }

    public function trips()
    {
        // what should I do here?
    }
}
```

```
class Place extends Model
{
    public function delivery()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Delivery::CLASS, 'delivery_id');
    }
}
```

```
class Trip extends Model
{
    public function departurePlace()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Place::CLASS, 'departure_place_id');
    }

    public function arrivalPlace()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Place::CLASS, 'arrival_place_id');
    }
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to get all the trips that are related to one delivery. Or, as another way of saying it, all the trips that connect all the places that one delivery must go through.
This is the SQL query that achieves the result I want:

```
select distinct trip.*
from delivery
    join place on (place.delivery_id = delivery.id)
    join trip on (place.id = trip.arrival_place_id or place.id = trip.departure_place_id)
```

I would like to have a `trips()` method on my `Delivery` model, that returns that result.
However I am quite confused as to how achieve that using Eloquent.

Comment: From the query I see above, it not seem like there is a direct link between a delivery and a trip. If I understand the query correctly, that would return all trips ever made on a place where the delivery have been.

Comment: Yes, exactly. There is no link between a delivery and a trip. Joining through places first is required, like the SQL query shows. Sorry, I just noticed there is a mistake in my question.

Comment: do you mean to get all trips from delivery through places?

Comment: @Saengdaet yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we could have simply used the `union` method to achieve this, but it seems that is doesn't work for `hasManyThrough`relations.

Anyway, I think `Eloquent` relations are not meant to be used to achieve such a specific query.

Instead, you may use `Eloquent` [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes) to achieve this.

So based on the answer of @Saengdaet, we can write two relations and then combine them with a `scope`:

(BTW: I don't know why you said that his code gave an error...)

```
class Delivery extends Model
{
    public function places()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Place::class);
    }

    public function outboundTrips()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Trip::class, 
            Place::class,
            "delivery_id", // Foreign key on places table
            "departure_place_id", // Foreign key on trips table
        );
    }

    public function inboundTrips()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Trip::class, 
            Place::class,
            "delivery_id", // Foreign key on places table
            "arrival_place_id", // Foreign key on trips table
        );
    }

    public function scopeTrips($query)
    {
        $deliveriesWithTrips = $query->with(['outboundTrips', 'inboundTrips'])->get();

        $trips = [];
        $deliveriesWithTrips->each(function ($elt) use (&$trips) {
            $trips[] = $elt->inboundTrips->merge($elt->outboundTrips);
        });

        return $trips;
    }
}
```

And now to retrieve all trips for a given delivery you simply write:

```
 Delivery::where('id', $id)->trips();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all trips from using `Delivery` model, you can use `hasManyThrough" relationship that provides a convenient shortcut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation.

But you have to choose which FK on your `Trip` model will you use to relate it

You can refer to ["has-many-through" relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

```
class Delivery extends Model
{
    public function places()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Place::CLASS, 'delivery_id');
    }

    public function trips()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
                       Trip::Class, 
                       Place::Class,
                       "delivery_id", // Foreign key on places table
                       "departure_place_id", // Foreign key on trips table
                       "id", // Local key on deliveries table
                       "id" // Local key on places table
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code was giving me an error. I changed it to this `return $this->hasManyThrough(Trip::Class, Place::Class, 'travel_id', 'departure_place_id');`> it works, but obviously this doesn't return me all the results I want, because it's missing the extra condition for `arrival_place_id`. While `hasManyThrough ` looks like an interesting feature (which I wasn't aware of), maybe it's not the right way of achieving the result I want?

Comment: ah I see, I only gave you example because I didn't know actually what is your FK and your PK.

Comment: maybe you can add more where condition to filtet them after **hasManyThrough**